# Stanford Classifier with Real Valued Features

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, stanford-nlp, text-classification

I'd like to use the [Stanford Classifier](http://nlp.stanford.edu/wiki/Software/Classifier) for text classification. My features are mostly textual, but there are some numeric features as well (e.g. the length of a sentence).

I started off with the [ClassifierExample](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/classify/ClassifierExample.java) and replaced the current features by a simple real valued feature `F` with value `100` if a stop light is `BROKEN` and `0.1` otherwise, which results in the following code (apart from the `makeStopLights()` function in line 10-16, this is just the code of the original ClassifierExample class):

```
public class ClassifierExample {

    protected static final String GREEN = "green";
    protected static final String RED = "red";
    protected static final String WORKING = "working";
    protected static final String BROKEN = "broken";

    private ClassifierExample() {} // not instantiable

    // the definition of this function was changed!!
    protected static Datum<String,String> makeStopLights(String ns, String ew) {
        String label = (ns.equals(ew) ? BROKEN : WORKING);
        Counter<String> counter = new ClassicCounter<>();
        counter.setCount("F", (label.equals(BROKEN)) ? 100 : 0.1);
        return new RVFDatum<>(counter, label);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a training set
        List<Datum<String,String>> trainingData = new ArrayList<>();
        trainingData.add(makeStopLights(GREEN, RED));
        trainingData.add(makeStopLights(GREEN, RED));
        trainingData.add(makeStopLights(GREEN, RED));
        trainingData.add(makeStopLights(RED, GREEN));
        trainingData.add(makeStopLights(RED, GREEN));
        trainingData.add(makeStopLights(RED, GREEN));
        trainingData.add(makeStopLights(RED, RED));
        // Create a test set
        Datum<String,String> workingLights = makeStopLights(GREEN, RED);
        Datum<String,String> brokenLights = makeStopLights(RED, RED);
        // Build a classifier factory
        LinearClassifierFactory<String,String> factory = new LinearClassifierFactory<>();
        factory.useConjugateGradientAscent();
        // Turn on per-iteration convergence updates
        factory.setVerbose(true);
        //Small amount of smoothing
        factory.setSigma(10.0);
        // Build a classifier
        LinearClassifier<String,String> classifier = factory.trainClassifier(trainingData);
        // Check out the learned weights
        classifier.dump();
        // Test the classifier
        System.out.println("Working instance got: " + classifier.classOf(workingLights));
        classifier.justificationOf(workingLights);
        System.out.println("Broken instance got: " + classifier.classOf(brokenLights));
        classifier.justificationOf(brokenLights);
    }

}
```

In my understanding of linear classifiers, feature `F` should make the classification task pretty easy - after all, we just need to check whether the value of `F` is greater than some threshold. However, the classifier returns `WORKING` on every instance in the test set.

Now my question is: Have I made something wrong, do I need to change some other parts of the code as well for real-valued features to work or is there something wrong with my understanding of linear classifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine.  Note that typically with a Maximum Entropy classifier you provide binary valued features (1 or 0).

Here is some more reading on Maximum Entropy classifiers: http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs124/lec/Maximum_Entropy_Classifiers

Look at slide titled: "Feature-Based Linear Classifiers" to see the specific probability calculation for Maximum Entropy classifiers.

Here is the formula for your example case with 1 feature and 2 classes ("works", "broken"):

`probability(c1) = exp(w1 * f1) / total
probability(c2) = exp(w2 * f1) / total
total = exp(w1 * f1) + exp(w2 * f1)`

w1 is the learned weight for "works" and w2 is the learned weight for "broken"

The classifier selects the higher probability.  Note that f1 = (100 or 0.1) your feature value.

If you consider your specific example data, since you have (2 classes, 1 feature, feature is always positive), it is not possible to build a maximum entropy classifier that will separate that data, it will always guess all one way or the other.

For sake of argument say `w1 > w2`.

Say `v > 0` is your feature value (either 100 or 0.1).

Then `w1 * v > w2 * v`, thus `exp(w1 * v) > exp(w2 * v)`, so you'll always assign more probability to class1 regardless of what value v has.